# Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, timeout

I am executing a query which is giving this error after that its showing another error 
**Error Code: 2006
MySQL server has gone away**

I Searched in Google and find some parameters to set like **connect_timeout,interactive_timeout and wait_timeout**

I increased all the parameters value from its existing value 
but still that error is showing.

Then i created 2 test table with less no of data, then the query executed well.

My live tables having more then 50k data and i am using federated table in the query

i think due to federated data and a lot of data in my table its taking more time.

My Query

```
SELECT TBL.NAME1,
   TBL.NAME2 
  FROM (SELECT MLD1.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME1,
           MLD2.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME2 
      FROM FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD1 
      JOIN FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD2 
     WHERE MLD1.LOGIN_NAME < MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
  ORDER BY NAME1,NAME2) TBL    
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_NAME1,
                      USER_NAME2 
                 FROM CONNECTION C
                WHERE (C.USER_NAME1 = TBL.NAME1 AND C.USER_NAME2 = TBL.NAME2));
```

Please help me to over come from this problem.

Thanks in advance